# Perpendicular function space

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let
$$\mathcal{A} = \left\{ f \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}) \; : \; \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \,  dx = 0, ~\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} xf(x)\, dx = 0 \right\},
$$

Here $f$ can be complexed valued.

Now that question that I am interested in is what is $\mathcal{A}^{\perp}$ in the Hilbert space $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$.?

I am looking for a simple description of it, and I have no idea of how to go about this.

Comment: In order to talk about $\int f$ and $\int x f(x) dx$, you need  $f$ and $x \mapsto x f(x)$ to be integrable, which is not guaranteed by $f \in L^2$.

Comment: Yes but here if $f\in\mathcal{A}$ then it is integrable and has integral $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{A}^\perp=\{0\}$ because $\mathcal{A}$ is a dense subspace of $L^2(\mathbb R)$.

Since continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^2$, it suffices to show that for every such function $f$ and for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $g\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\|f-g\|_{L^2}<\epsilon$. To this end, consider 
$$g=f+a\chi_{[-N,N]}+b(\chi_{[0,N]}-\chi_{[-N,0]})$$
where $N$ is large and the constants $a,b$ are chosen so that $g\in \mathcal {A}$. Specifically, 
$$a=-\frac{1}{2N}\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)\,dx,\quad b=-\frac{1}{N^2} \int_{\mathbb R} xf(x)\,dx$$
Since
$$\|f-g\|_{L^2}\le 2N |a|^2 +2N|b|^2   $$ 
where the right-hand side tends to $0$ as $N\to\infty$, the claim follows.